# 24 volt 2.2a to 24volt 0.75mA

Tags: power-supply, amperage, adapter

I just want to know if a 24v 2.2A output power adaptor can be use on a 24v 0.75mA unit? I have not tried it because I'm afraid that it might harm the unit due to a huge difference in Ampere..

I would really appreciate if someone can answer me this..

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. 75mA is how much your device consumes; 2A is what the power supply is capable of, not what it will "push through". Voltage is what you must make sure matches.